# microsoft solver foundation constraint logical erro

Tags: c#, ms-solver-foundation

This is the formula that I want to add as a constraint to the Microsoft solver foundation.

I am using the **`SumTermBuilder`** class in this code but solver gives me the wrong result and there is no compilation error for this code. Why am I getting the wrong result?

**Code:**

```
var N_Available_Total = new SumTermBuilder(decisions.Count());
var OM_Available_Total = new SumTermBuilder(decisions.Count());
var Hourly = new SumTermBuilder(96);
for (int i = 1; i < 97; i++)
{
    foreach (var item in newfeed)
    {
        float x = item.N_ED_Available_at_time_Total[i]/100;
        float y = item.OM_ED_Available_at_time_Total[i]/100;
        //get decision variables list
        var feeddecision = model.Decisions.First(it => it.Name == item.feed);
        //summation of all decision variables 
        N_Available_Total.Add(feeddecision * x); // For N
        OM_Available_Total.Add(feeddecision * y); // for OM
    }
    Hourly.Add((Model.Sqrt(Model.Power((25 - ((N_Available_Total.ToTerm() / OM_Available_Total.ToTerm()))), 2)))/96);
}
var SIConstraint = (25 - ((Hourly.ToTerm())) / 25) >= 0.9;
model.AddConstraint("SI", SIConstraint);
```

Comment: Arrays are usually 0-indexed, so the line `for (int i = 1; i < 97; i++)` looks wrong to me; I'd expect the loop to look like `for (int i = 0; i < 96; i++)`.

Comment: ok, but it doesn't effect my result when i use 0 or 1 because it is a dictionary and i try to use 0 instead and the same wrong result obtained

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail about what's going wrong, and what `item` is?